Hypothetical probable versus improbable future versus imperfect subjunctive with conditional. Which one?
I have researched on FluentU and elsewhere the following question. I also asked a native Spanish speaker but I still am unclear.
This is an exam role-play.
Imagine I am hiring a campervan and I say to the agent:

If we had blinds, we would sleep better.

Ok, I know for years how to form the future imperfect subjunctive and the conditional tenses. I usually know when to use them.
However, with this type of example I am not 100 percent sure.
Ok, the hiring of the campervan is a certainty in a few weeks or months.
I am suggesting/implying that blinds would be advantageous/welcome if there were a possibility of getting the blinds.
As it is possible or probable, in other words, not something as crazy as aliens landing or winning the lottery, I think it will more than likely be:

Si tenemos persianas, dormiremos mejor [present + future].

vs

Si tuviéramos persianas, dormiríamos mejor [Imperfect subjunctive + conditional].

Although, I still say to myself this is still a bit of a wild, imaginative leap into the future where it depends on the good will or whims of the agent. Therefore, I still wonder, if the second option is the correct one.

I will leave it to the native speakers to provide an answer but the second one seems superior to me since it refers to a hypothetical, if we were to have blinds.

Both are possible.
The first one takes for granted that blinds will or may be available. It may sound a bit impolite, or it may be stated after expressing one's wish or after the van rental's offer:
Customer: Nos gustaría con persianas. Si tenemos persianas, dormiremos mejor [present + future] (We would like it with blinds. If they are available, we'll sleep better)
Rental: Tenemos con persianas o sin persianas. //
Customer: Si tenemos persianas, dormiremos mejor [present + future]
The second one is either more polite or considers the availability of blinds less probable:

Si tuviéramos persianas, dormiríamos mejor [past subjuntive + conditional] (If we had blinds, we'd sleep better)

For the sake of clarity, the first sentence is more factual:

If it is fact that we have blinds, then we'll sleep better.

while the second one is more hypothetical:

If it were the case that we had blinds, then we'd sleep better.


I understand your answer but I am still torn between which to use. I mean,it is a sort of hopeful suggestion on the customer's part ,or an indirect question. As I said to Tac as I am Irish ,I think we use a type of indirect humour to hopefully get what we want. l think I will include one of Tac's suggestions along with either one of my original statements. Again, I would like to see what lots of people say. Tnx

I've made an addition that might help you decide which to use.

La primera no se va a entender como formular una petición. Algunos van a entender que hay una especie de petición, deseo o sugerencia con el condicional hipotético (por el verbo en condicional), pero según mi experiencia ninguna de las dos va a funcionar. El español es mucho más directo para pedir cosas, por lo tanto iría con alguna de las siguientes:

Podría ser con persianas, por favor?
Hay alguna posibilidad de que venga con persianas?
Viene con persianas?

Sin asertividad es probable que el agente no entienda nada.

@tac.Yes,I like your answer and I think Spanish can be more direct.I always laugh at 'dígame'' when answering the phone.  I am from Ireland and I think we often suggest something in the hope someone may give us what we want. We may use a touch of humour with it.It is all very good-natured.I get your point though.I would like to hear others thoughts also on my original question.

Concuerdo, con ninguna de las 2 frases propuestas la persona que las escucha considerará que es una petición.

Cambiaría el "viene" por "tiene", pues las persianas están contenidas dentro de algo (el casacarro o la habitación). Lo de "vienen" suena a que van a llegar de algún lado.
